# Bring a UIViewController in navigationController stack to top

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, stack

I have a UINavigationController with multiple UIViewControllers in stack. I now want to bring a particular UIViewController from the stack to top without popping the other UIViewControllers in-between.

Can i even achieve this?...considering its FIFO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. If you feel the need to do this, it is likely that there is something that needs to be changed in the flow of your application.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do this with the following code

```
for controller in navigationController?.viewControllers { 
  if controller is MyViewController { 
    nextController = controller
    } 
  }

var controllers = navigationController?.viewControllers              
controllers.removeAtIndex(controllers.indexOf(nextController!)!)
controllers.append(nextController!)
navigationController?.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: false)
```

HOWEVER... to quote the famous jeff Goldbloom...  too busy wondering if we could to stop and think if we should... this may not be acceptable, but it seems to work

there are some implications with manipulating the view controller stack as an array... eg. what happens to the root view controller... did you define it in your storyboard?

Comment: when programmatically implementing navigation controller, pushing an array of view controllers to the stack causes the new index[0] to be the root view controller... it seems fine...

Comment: depending on how large you let your view controller stack get, i could see memory management being an issue